# Getting "Cannot read property 'geocodingForm' of undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using reactive forms from Angular Material. I am trying to remove the error mentioned. I am able to get the value of the input upon submit using the console.log, but I keep having the error when just trying to put the value in a variable "address" under the onSubmit method.

I had already tried the following:

- var address=this.geocodingForm.get('input').value
- var address=this.geocodingForm.value.input

as well as changing the var to let.

**geocoding.component.html**

```
    <mat-grid-tile colspan='60'>
        <div #gmap class="map"></div>
    </mat-grid-tile>

    <mat-grid-tile colspan='40'>
    <form novalidate [formGroup]="geocodingForm" #gform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <h4>Geocoding Service</h4>
      <p>
        <input matInput formControlName="input" placeholder="address" type="text" required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.input">{{formErrors.input}}</mat-error>
      </p>
      <button type="submit" mat-button class="background-primary text-floral-white" [disabled]="gform.form.invalid">Submit</button>
    </form>

    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

**geocoding.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-geocoding',
  templateUrl: './geocoding.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./geocoding.component.css']
})
export class GeocodingComponent implements OnInit {

  geocodingForm: FormGroup;
  map: google.maps.Map;
  errMess: string;
  mapProp ={};
  @ViewChild('gform', { static: false }) geocodingFormDirective;
  @ViewChild('gmap') gmapElement: any;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,//FormBuilders is an array of groups(i.e. Name, email, Address (new form group as address can be separated further like state, city, etc.))
  ) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.5793, 73.8143),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, this.mapProp);
  }

  formErrors = {
    'input': ''
  };

  validationMessages = {
    'input': {
      'required': 'Please provide an address'
    }
  };

  createForm() {
    this.geocodingForm = this.fb.group({
      input: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });

    this.geocodingForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));

    this.onValueChanged(); // (re)set validation messages now

  }

  onValueChanged(data?: any) { //data parameter is optional by use of "?"
    if (!this.geocodingForm) { return; }
    const form = this.geocodingForm;
    for (const field in this.formErrors) {
      if (this.formErrors.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
        // clear previous error message (if any)
        this.formErrors[field] = '';
        const control = form.get(field);
        if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
          const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
          for (const key in control.errors) {
            if (control.errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) { //condition unnecessary?
              this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

   onSubmit() {

    console.log(this.geocodingForm.value.input);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, this.mapProp);

    function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
      var address=this.geocodingForm.get('input').value;

      geocoder.geocode({'address': this.address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: resultsMap,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
        } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
      });
    }


    this.geocodingFormDirective.resetForm();
    this.geocodingForm.reset({
      input: ''
    });
  }


}
```

I just expect to not receive the error :

> Cannot read property 'geocodingForm' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your are using conventional `function` where the value of `this` is dependent how the function is invoked.

Use arrow function instead  like

```
geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap){}
```

& remove the nested keyword `function`

It will be be even better if you can remove the nested `function` and create separate function in the  component class

Comment: `Use arrow function instead like` ... like what? you haven't shown an arrow function

Comment: Separating the function worked among other things. Although I could use some more specific explanations on why this is.

Comment: @JaromandaX - I had done what you suggested and I am also not entirely sure about the benifits of the arrow function on this part aside from making it simpler than the traditional ones. Also, const doesn't work, I had to remove it

Comment: @Robby = using arrow functions was **not** my idea, I just pointed out that brk code doesn't show any arrow functions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199162/discussion-between-robby-and-jaromanda-x).